# How to show an event triggered in a SQL database in a html page?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, triggers, xampp

I'm developing a simple social network for a university project.
I'm facing some problems trying to implement a specific request: I can't change the way it's done, I have to do it that way, but I don't know how.

Suppose that the social network is made only by two types of users: teachers and students. A teacher is able to submit a news related to a course, and every student that is subscribed to that course will receive a message in his inbox about that. The problem is, I have to develop it using SQL triggers.

More specifically, the inbox is a sql table with multiple entries (message code, sender code, receiver code, message object, etc.); the news are stored in another sql table (news code, text, etc.).
The social network is implemented using XAMPP.

In the home of the SN, I have a button which shows "# unread messages", and when a new news is submitted by a teacher, if the user is subscribed to the course to which the news belong, that "#" should update consequently, without reloading the page.

Any idea?

Comment: So the trigger requirement is far from being the problem, isn't it? I'm afraid you're basically asking how to write a web application with database backend—the type of generic question this site is not designed to answer.

Comment: Rather than websockets, server sent events might be the way forward to solve this one as they are much easier to implement. The database triggers and the sse would function independantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for that.

An alternative could be an interval that regularly asks the backend for changes (not a good solution, though).

Answer (score 0):

You can use signal r

The web socket version for asp.net

With this technology your page subscribes to listen if any change occurs for example for a new record in news. If an update is available the page receives the information and you update the content with out refresing the whole page.

http://www.asp.net/signalr